# Good site to get project feedback?

Tags: asp.net, project-management, feedback, user-feedback

I have a personal project I've been working on in my spare time. It's far from complete, but I want feedback on the UI and the functionality that has made it in so far.  Where is a good location to get useful feedback without being persecuted for the post being unrelated to the site's purpose?

The project is a website. I'm not posting a link so people don't think this is spam. Will add a link if comments so request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend asking for a review of your site on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/news).  This site was created and maintained by [Paul Graham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham) who also founded [Y Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Combinator), a company focused on helping startups in their early stages. As a result, Hacker News is read by a community heavily focused on anything startup-related and, therefore, are very receptive to critiquing and reviewing new sites.

When you [submit your review request](http://news.ycombinator.com/submit), you probably should word the title of your post as such:

> Ask HN: please review my site [my
>   site]

and describe a bit of its intent.

(Here is a recent example: [Ask HN: Review my newest site](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=491556))

Answer (score 2):

I think the Business of Software forums are a good place for this.

[Joel on Software discussions](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz)

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest you to add a [feedback form](http://userthought.com/information/fully_customizable_feedback_form) with content highlighting feature to your website.

All the functionality requires a change of only 1 line of HTML.

**Content Highlighting** feature will allow your users to select exactly what they want to describe or point to against a feedback message.

**Rich Feedback Analytics** will help you to understand what your users want from your service.

Hope this helps.